# Can't start locator on Apache Geode on Centos 7 minimal

Tags: gemfire, geode

I've tried the master branch and the develop branch, as well as the gemfire rpm from Pivotal. Same result :

```
start locator --name=test
Starting a GemFire Locator in /root/incubator-geode/gemfire-assembly/build/install/test...
.....Locator in /root/incubator-geode/gemfire-assembly/build/install/test on CentOS-72-64-minimal[10334] as test is currently online.
Process ID: 786
Uptime: 2 seconds
GemFire Version: 1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
Java Version: 1.8.0_72
Log File: /root/incubator-geode/gemfire-assembly/build/install/test/test.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.enable-cluster-configuration=true -Dgemfire.load-cluster-configuration-from-dir=false -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: /root/incubator-geode/gemfire-assembly/build/install/apache-geode/lib/gemfire-core-1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar:/root/incubator-geode/gemfire-assembly/build/install/apache-geode/lib/gemfire-core-dependencies.jar

Please use "connect --locator=CentOS-72-64-minimal[10334]" to connect Gfsh to the locator.

Cluster configuration service is up and running.

gfsh>connect --locator=CentOS-72-64-minimal[10334]
Connecting to Locator at [host=CentOS-72-64-minimal, port=10334] ..
Exception caused JMX Manager startup to fail because: 'HTTP service failed to start'
```

In the logs of the locator, this is what I get:

```
Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@36d5715{/gemfire,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/root/incubator-geode/gemfire-assembly/build/install/apache-geode/tools/Extensions/gemfire-web-1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.war}

[error 2016/01/29 11:11:58.538 CET test <locator request thread[1]> tid=0x23] Jmx manager could not be started because HTTP service failed to start
com.gemstone.gemfire.management.ManagementException: HTTP service failed to start
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.ManagementAgent.startHttpService(ManagementAgent.java:280)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.ManagementAgent.startAgent(ManagementAgent.java:126)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.SystemManagementService.startManager(SystemManagementService.java:476)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.JmxManagerLocator.findJmxManager(JmxManagerLocator.java:104)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.JmxManagerLocator.processRequest(JmxManagerLocator.java:57)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.InternalLocator$PrimaryHandler.processRequest(InternalLocator.java:1333)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.tcpserver.TcpServer$3.run(TcpServer.java:387)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.JettyHelper.startJetty(JettyHelper.java:149)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.ManagementAgent.startHttpService(ManagementAgent.java:252)
    ... 9 more
```

I googled to no avail. My ports are fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

It seems to http service port 7070 already in use.
Could you please try to start locator

```
start locator --name=test --J=-Dgemfire.http-service-port=8080 --J=-Dgemfire.http-service-bind-address=hostname
```